# Angular: Service Inside nested *ngFor is not working

Tags: angular

I tried following Approach,but for some reason I can't use a service inside ngFor. There are too many http-request calling. And apart from bilanz the inner ngFor does not display anything.

```
<div *ngFor="let bilanz of $bilanz | async">
  <input type="checkbox" name="land" (change)="checkFilter($event)" value="{{bilanz.LAND}}" />{{bilanz.LAND}}<br />
  <div *ngFor="let b of stadtService.getBilanz([{land: bilanz.LAND}]) | async" class="stadt">
      <input type="checkbox" name="stadt" (change)="checkFilter($event)" value="b.STADT" />{{b.STADT}}<br />
</div>
</div>
```

In my FilterComponent I have added the following line:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.$bilanz = this.laenderService.getBilanz();
  }
```

My laenderBilanz is as follows. stadtBilanz is similar:

```
  // GET
  public getBilanz(options=undefined): Observable<Bilanz[]> {
      const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',

          }),
      };
      var url = `${this.serverUrl}/bilanz/laender`;
      if(options!=undefined) {
          for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
          var object = options[i];
          console.log(object);
            for (var property in object) {
                if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    if(i==0) {
                        url+="?"+property+"[]="+object[property];
                    } else {
                        url+="&"+property+"[]="+object[property];
                    }
                }
            }
          }
      }

      console.log(url);
      return this._http.get<Bilanz[]>(url, httpOptions);
  }
```

StadtService:

```
 // GET
  public getBilanz(options=undefined, ascending=undefined): Observable<Any[]> {
      const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',

          }),
      };
      var url = `${this.serverUrl}/bilanz/stadt`;

      if(options!=undefined) {
          for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
          var object = options[i];
          console.log(object);
          var s = 0;
            for (var property in object) {
                if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    if((i==0)&&(s==0)) {
                        url+="?"+property+"[]="+object[property];
                    } else {
                        url+="&"+property+"[]="+object[property];
                    }
                }
                s++;
            }
          }
      }

      if(ascending!=undefined) {
        url+="?ascending="+ascending;
      }
      console.log(url);
      return this._http.get<Bilanz[]>(url, httpOptions);
  }
```

I can also provide the rest-api if it is necessary.

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: no error but the http-request goes endless and no result shows up except for $bilanz

Comment: You need to show exactly how `$bilanz` is being set. Also you need to show the contents of `laenderService.getBilanz()` as well as `stadtService.getBilanz()`.

Comment: first of all subscribe to `this.laenderService.getBilanz()`

Comment: @nircraft no need to subscribe "async" pipe does it automatically. [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Answer (score 0):

i believe your issue here

```
stadtService.getBilanz([{land: bilanz.LAND}])
```

here is working [test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgway9) you are adding `stadtService` not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `*ngFor` and async pipe look correct.

I think you should **verify** your `url` and `httpOptions`

```
return this._http.get<Bilanz[]>(url, httpOptions); // Make sure you get a valid response
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgiz5k

Comment: I'm getting a valid response. I already used it for other Displays.